# C++ operator overloading: no known conversion from object to reference?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

When I try to compile the following (g++ 4.6.3)

```
class A {};

A& operator*=( A& a, const A& b )
{
  return a;
}

A operator*( const A& a, const A& b )
{
  return A( a ) *= b;
}

int main( int, char*[] )
{
  A a, b;

  a = a*b;

  return 0;
}
```

I get the error

```
/tmp/test.cxx: In function ‘A operator*(const A&, const A&)’:
/tmp/test.cxx:14:20: error: no match for ‘operator*=’ in ‘(* & a) *= b’
/tmp/test.cxx:14:20: note: candidate is:
/tmp/test.cxx:6:1: note: A& operator*=(A&, const A&)
/tmp/test.cxx:6:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘A&’
```

This puzzles me - how can a conversion from a class to a reference to that class not be known?

Changing the declaration of class A as follows does not have any effect:

```
class A
{
public:
  A() {}
  A( const A& ) {}
};
```

Same error.

I would be extremely grateful for hints as to what's going on here.

Comment: You can fix this issue by declaring the operator in the scope of the class. Then your method signature would look like: 'A operator*(const A & rhs) const;' If you want to use the compound operator for the implementation you can then write: 'return *this *= rhs'

Comment: @Paranaix: No, you can't use `operator*=` on `*this` inside a `const` member function, since it would modify `*this`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah your completly right. I wanted to write it as one liner and accidently removed the whole magic. The trick is to create a copy from 'this'. In example: 'A ret = *this; ret *= rhs; return ret;'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like Lucian said, you cannot bind a temporary object to a non-const reference. The expectance of the compiler is that the object will cease to exist after the expression so it makes no sense to modify it.

To fix your code, remove the temporary (making the argument `const&` makes no sense in `operator *=`):

```
A operator*(A a, const A& b)
{
    return a *= b;
}
```

Comment: @Ben I need coffee … To defend my honour, this (pass by value) is how I would normally write it when I’m awake.

Comment: Much simpler.  And more optimized, since it can move when the actual parameter is an x-value.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `A( a )`, you create a temporary of type A ( a rvalue ) that you copy-construct with `a`. C++ states that no rvalue could be passed as non const reference. Visual Studio is a bit sloppy about this rule, but gcc and the like enforce it.

To fix, try this ( which is exactly the same, but you create a lvalue by naming that variable ). More on l- and r-value [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/)

```
A operator*( A a, const A& b )
{
   return a *= b;
}
```

Comment: Same objection as I posted on Konrad's answer.

Comment: Both are correct. But sometimes, you don't need to create a copy of a to do the * operation. e.g. Vector *operator will not use *= to express *

Comment: "Visual Studio is a bit sloppy about this rule...":  Visual Studio catches this if you're running at warning level 4 / treat warnings as errors (as is wise).

Comment: @crazyjul in the vector example, don't you think the compiler would optimize away the copying.

Comment: (To clarify, the objection I formerly posted on Konrad's answer, was that the compiler can copy more efficiently, just make the parameter pass-by-value.  That also enables the move optimization where appropriate.)

Comment: @enobayram: There is no `operator*=` which accepts two vectors, since the result is not a vector.

Comment: @enobayram In release, it will. But not in debug. And working as game programmer, debug speed is an important aspect

Comment: @BenVoigt good point, but that wasn't my point. Replace "Vector" with "Complex number".

Comment: @crazyjul you're right, I should also care more about debug speed. Not    compiling every `.cpp` file at the same optimization level usually saves me though.

Comment: As was already answered, the C++ standard states that 

"[...] an lvalue reference to non-const cannot be bound to an rvalue [...]"

and, C++ 2015-05 working draft, 8.5.3(5.2):

"[...] the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference."

The solution here fits well with the suggested design:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators