# GLM Math lib compile errors with GCC

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, glm-math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [C++ operator overloading: no known conversion from object to reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236240/c-operator-overloading-no-known-conversion-from-object-to-reference)

I am using [GLM lib](http://glm.g-truc.net/) (version 0.9.4) for an OpenGL renderer which I port now to Linux.I had no problems with compilations with MS VS2010 .
Now ,when trying to compile on Linux with GCC (version 4.7.2) I have some weird errors related to methods which get GLM matrices as input.

For example.Here is the declaration :

```
  void SetProjection(mat4 &matr);
```

And the definition is:

```
  void TransformState::SetProjection(mat4 &matr){

    _projection=matr;

 }
```

And on some place I use it like this:

```
_transform.SetProjection(perspective(_fov , _viewportW/(float)_viewportH,_nearPlane , _farPlane));
```

The GCC compiler throws the following :

**../../Documents/XXX/XXX/XXXengine/src/cameras/XXXX.cpp:120:104: error: no matching function for call to ‘ie_engine::TransformState::SetProjection(glm::detail::tmat4x4)’**

And for the above mentioned declaration method I am getting this error:

**../../Documents/XXX/XXXX/XXXengine/include/TransformState.h:31:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘glm::detail::tmat4x4’ to ‘glm::mat4& {aka glm::detail::tmat4x4&}’**

What is the problem? As far as I know GLM does work with GCC.

Comment: `SetProjection` for reasons unknown wants a non-const reference. You are trying to give it a temporary. A temporary cannot be bound to a non-const reference. Fix the signature of `SetProjection` so that it accepts a `const mat4&` like every good little function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void SetProjection(mat4 &matr);
```

Why are you not taking the parameter by `const&` instead of by non-const `&`? That looks like a mistake, since `SetProjection` is not *modifying* the parameter.

That's where your compiler error is coming from. The return value of `perspective` is a temporary. And a temporary cannot be stored by a non-const `&`.

Comment: you are completely right on this.It has to be const& but I am really curious why on VC ++ compiler I get no complaints about it .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189420/one-vs2010-bug-allowing-binding-non-const-reference-to-rvalue-without-even-a-w or many others, that's a pain.

Comment: @MarcGlisse WOW! That is a nice finding :) Good to know especially being GCC noob.